# Firefox selenium : listbox is not displaying

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, xpath

Firefox Version : 50.0.2

Autocomplete listbox is not displaying.I tried the below methods and its not working in latest firefox version.

I tried clicking the textbox after sending the keys also.

Method :1

```
getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement element = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(elementId));
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys(value);
```

Method :2

```
for (int i = 0; i < user_id.length(); i++){
            char c = user_id.charAt(i);
            String s = new StringBuilder().append(c).toString();
            UiActions.sendKeys(driver, xpath, s);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
```

Comment: reference : https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6981

Comment: would you please add relevant HTML code? from the question, I understand that though you enter text into the text field, content is not displayed. Am I right? Also, mention the error trace if any. I suggest to use the latest geckodriver version as it is still in development phase.

Comment: am using gecko version : v0.11.  error : xpath is not a legal expression